# SQLServerException: Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I made this little prototype with Spring Boot, working fine with a Postgres database, but I had to change it to an MSSQL container, and now I get this SQLServerException.

This is what I have got:

- An entity called StructuralElement
- the table structural_element, and I put an entry in this table by hand.
- The database is an MSSQL container with the database name "master" and schema name "dbo".
- a JpaRepository called StructuralElementRepository

I get the exception every time the `.getAll()` method of the repository is called.
I'm not sure what's going on, but I guess hibernate/jpa can't make the connection to the correct table?

The flyway script

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StructuralElement
(
    id          INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    name        NVARCHAR(128)      NULL,
    description NVARCHAR(4000)     NULL,     -- could also be NTEXT
    sequel      INT                NOT NULL, -- order within the Hierarchy
    FK_parent   INT                NULL      -- Hierarchy
);
```

The application.properties

```
server.port=8080

# JPA / Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

#Database Connection
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=master
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=prototype_2020

spring.flyway.schemas=dbo
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.placeholders.schemaName: dbo
```

The entity

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "StructuralElement")
public class StructuralElement {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Long sequel;
```

The repository

```
@Repository
public interface PlanstellenRepository extends JpaRepository<Planstelle, Long> {
    
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.prototype</groupId>
    <artifactId>userservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT: Changed to correct flyway script.

Comment: In your migration script you name your table `StructuralElement_Function` but in entity definition there is a `@Table` annotation with name `StructuralElement`. Is this intentional?

Comment: You should NOT be using the master database for your own tables nor should you be using the built-in sa account.

Comment: @nkrivenko Sorry, stupid me copied the wrong part of the script

Comment: @SMor You're absolutely right, I will change that as soon as the mapping is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by renaming the table to `structural_element`.
The `@Table(name="StructuralElement")` annotation isn't working like expected.